# Examine lucene.net custom query after analyzer tokenizes

Tags: lucene, umbraco, lucene.net, examine

I'm using Examine in Umbraco to query Lucene index of content nodes. I have a field "completeNodeText" that is the concatenation of all the node properties (to keep things simple and not search across multiple fields).

I'm accepting user-submitted search terms. When the search term is multiple words (ie, "firstterm secondterm"), I want the resulting query to be an OR query: Bring me back results where fullNodeText is firstterm OR secondterm.

I want:

```
{+completeNodeText:"firstterm ? secondterm"}
```

but instead, I'm getting:

```
{+completeNodeText:"firstterm secondterm"}
```

If I search for "firstterm OR secondterm" instead of "firstterm secondterm", then the generated query is correctly: `{+completeNodeText:"firstterm ? secondterm"}`

I'm using the following API calls:

```
var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ExternalSearcher"];
var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();
var query = searchCriteria.Field("completeNodeText", term).Compile();
```

Is there an easy way to force Examine to generate this "OR" query? Or do I have to manually construct the raw query by calling the StandardAnalyzer to tokenize the user input and concatenating together a query by iterating through the tokens? And bypassing the entire Examine fluent query API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that question mark means what you think it means.

It looks like you are generating a PhraseQuery, but you want two disjoint TermQueries.  In [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html), a phrase query is enclosed in quotes.

```
"firstterm secondterm"
```

A phrase query is looking for precisely that phrase, with the two terms appearing consecutively, and in order.  Placing an `OR` within a phrase query does not perform any sort of boolean logic, but rather treats it as the word "OR".  The question mark is a placeholder using in `PhraseQuery.toString()` to represent a removed stop word (See [#Lucene-1396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1396)).  You are still performing a phrasequery, but now it is expecting a three word phrase `firstterm`, followed by a removed stop word, followed by `secondterm`

To simply search for two separate terms, get rid of the quotes.

```
 firstterm secondterm
```

Will search for any document with either of those terms (with higher score given to documents with both).

Comment: I didn't realize that meant it was a phrase query. I guess what I want to do is have Examine generate a query that is an OR of each token in the original user-submitted text.

Comment: But I want Examine to use the StandardAnalyzer to tokenize everything so that I don't have to manually tokenize the user input myself (by splitting on ' ' and filtering out stop words) and then generate individual "OR" field queries for each of these manually generated tokens.

Is it possible to have Examine/Lucene take the token stream and then generate individual OR field queries for each token?

Comment: The QueryParser should handle that for you.  Did you read the [query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) I linked to?  Is there some specific problem you are seeing here?

Comment: I think my problem is that the Examine fluent API `Examine.LuceneEngine.SearchCriteria.LuceneSearchCriteria.Field(string fieldName, string fieldValue)` is generating a phrase query instead of two OR term queries. It uses the StandardAnalyzer to tokenize the input text (which is what I want it to do), but it doesn't generate the exact type of query that I want. I don't see a way to change this behavior without re-implementing the fluent API, so I think I will just have to manually generate the raw query `completeNodeText:(firstterm OR secondterm)`

Comment: (cont'd) Which means either string concatenation / manually tokenizing the input string OR using a different strongly-typed query API (other than the Examine fluent API) ?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, I believe you need to use `RawQuery`.  The Field query isn't run through a QueryParser, so it won't generate multiple terms from your string (ie. Lucene query syntax, doesn't come into play for it).  One note, if is simplifies things, `completeNodeText:(firstterm secondterm)` is adequate since `OR` is effectively the default operator.